# Total allocation exceeds 95.00% (1,020,054,720 bytes) of heap memory Scaling row group sizes to 95.00% for 8 writers when have set driver_memory

Tags: python, pyspark

I use pyspark in cline mode.Unzip 7z files and extract the rows i want in to a parquet file.And this warn occurs:

`WARN MemoryManager: Total allocation exceeds 95.00% (1,020,054,720 bytes) of heap memory Scaling row group sizes to 95.00% for 8 writers`

I searched and find out that I should set larger driver memory& executor memory to make sure the heap memory is enough.So I edit $SPARK_HOME/conf/spark-defaults.conf and add

```
spark.driver.memory 128g
spark.executor.memory 128g
```

and then I create a py file to make sure this makes sense.

```
[('spark.driver.extraJavaOptions', '-XX:+IgnoreUnrecognizedVMOptions --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang.invoke=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang.reflect=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.net=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.nio=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent.atomic=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/sun.nio.cs=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/sun.security.action=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/sun.util.calendar=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.security.jgss/sun.security.krb5=ALL-UNNAMED'), ('spark.app.name', 'LargeFileReader'), ('spark.driver.port', '42563'), ('spark.app.submitTime', '1680190868014'), ('spark.executor.id', 'driver'), ('spark.executor.memory', '128g'), ('spark.app.id', 'local-1680190869088'), ('spark.driver.host', '10.77.50.130'), ('spark.app.startTime', '1680190868182'), ('spark.rdd.compress', 'True'), ('spark.executor.extraJavaOptions', '-XX:+IgnoreUnrecognizedVMOptions --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang.invoke=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang.reflect=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.net=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.nio=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent.atomic=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/sun.nio.cs=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/sun.security.action=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/sun.util.calendar=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.security.jgss/sun.security.krb5=ALL-UNNAMED'), ('spark.serializer.objectStreamReset', '100'), ('spark.master', 'local[*]'), ('spark.submit.pyFiles', ''), ('spark.submit.deployMode', 'client'), ('spark.ui.showConsoleProgress', 'true'), ('spark.driver.memory', '128g')]
```

I see both driver memory and executor memory 128g,so I restart my program again.But this warn still occurs,which means the memory is still default 1g.And now I am confused.

Answer (score 0):

I may know why.

I login the Ubuntu system both from VS code terminal and Windows powershell.I use `source ~/.bashrc` in VS code terminal to update the environment varible I set like $JAVA_HOME.
When I check SparkUI I find the $JAVA_HOME is still the default mode.And I use

```
echo $JAVA_HOME
```

to check and know the problem.Finally I update .bashrc in the powershell too.

> "Note that changing environment variables only affects the current session, so you need to restart any terminals or VS Code itself to pick up new values."

Above is from VScode official documents.Finally I renew the environment varible and recheck,SparkUI show ans I want.

I am a beginner in pyspark,If I have any mistake,please point out ,thx!